# How to print a Vec without brackets

Tags: vector, rust

How can I print a Vec without brackets?

```
let v = vec![1,2,3];
```

I want to print it like this:

```
1 2 3
```

not like this:

```
[1,2,3]
```

What I tried:

```rust
let mut v = vec![s; k];
println!("{}", format!("{:?}", v)[1..]);
```

but I got error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:16:9
    |
16  |         println!("{}", format!("{:?}", v)[1..]);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally just want to print the values, you could do something like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    
    v.iter().for_each(|val| print!("{} ", val));
}
```

If you want to concatenate them into a `String`, you could do this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let  v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let str = v.iter().map(|val| format!("{}", val)).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(" ");
    println!("{}", str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what youre asking... bit if all you need to do is print just like that... you could to this...

```
fn main() {
    let v = [1,2,3];

    for x in v {
        print!("{} ", x);
    }
    println!()
}
```